# Can I combine these two jQuery events somehow?

Tags: jquery

I have the following. Is there some way that I can combine these two events? Do I need to have some kind of foreach function?

```
$('#AccountID').focus(function() {
    $('option[value="99"]', this).remove();
});

$('#TopicID').focus(function() {
    $('option[value="99"]', this).remove();
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a different selector:

```
$('#AccountID, #TopicID').focus(...);
```

Or, better yet, add a common class and use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by combining the events.  You could do this:

```
$('#AccountID, #TopicID')
    .focus(function () {
                $('option[value="99"]', this).remove();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors use the css selectors, so the selector `a,b`  means, select `a` **and** `b`

```
$('#AccountID, #TopicID').focus(function () {
    $('option[value="99"]', this).remove();
});
```

Note that, when you give a context to the jQuery function, it's executed in this way:

```
$(this).find('option[value="99"]').remove();
```

So you can do it yourself and save the (though small) trip and overhead.

[**jQuery source code:**](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js)

```
...
...
...
// HANDLE: $(expr, context)
// (which is just equivalent to: $(context).find(expr)
} else {
    return this.constructor( context ).find( selector );
}
```